# Adding imageview as a subview in scrollview swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am adding images to scrollview but just getting one image in the scrollview, I dont know why I am not seing any other images but just empty scroll except one image

This is what I have tried 
in `viewdidload`

```
  imageScroll = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 230, height: 250))
  imageScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 2000)       
  imageScroll.backgroundColor = .white
```

in function

```
for (b,c) in zip(photoGotArray, 0..<totalPhotosGot) {

   photoDataVarOk = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: b) as? NSData
   newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 230, height: 200))
   newImageView.viewWithTag(c)
   newImageView.image = UIImage(data: photoDataVarOk! as Data)
   self.imageScroll.addSubview(newImageView)

}
```

here is the image with just one image and rest of the empty scrollview

[image]

Comment: You are adding the image to the same imageView over and over again, as a result you are replacing the images every time. What you need to do is create a new instance of an `imageView` and also set a new frame which is below the one added before it. (You need to do some math).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Y to be incrementing as according to your code all images have the same frame

```
let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50 + ( 200 * i ) , width: 230, height: 200))
```

set `i` as you want or from the loop parameters

//

```
for (c,b) in photoGotArray.enumerated() {

    photoDataVarOk = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: b) 
    let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50 + ( 200 * c), width: 230, height: 200))
    newImageView.viewWithTag(c)
    newImageView.image = UIImage(data: photoDataVarOk!)
    self.imageScroll.addSubview(newImageView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let newImageView = UIImageView()
newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: yourImageHight * (indexLoop), width: 230, height: 200))

in your loop